# Swift Drawing App is Laggy

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, drawing, lag

I am currently working on a drawing app. I'm building it for iOS, and am using Swift 3 to do so.

It's just a basic drawing app, but I'm trying to add an extra feature. I started with a UIScrollView, then added an Image View to that scroll view. All of the drawing part is done with the image view. When you first launch the app, the scrollview is completely zoomed in. When you switch to "zoom mode" this allows you to pinch to zoom. The problem is, when you first open the app, when you draw while zoomed in, the drawing is really fuzzy. In order to fix this, I can use a line of code like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((self.view.frame.size), false, 7.0)
```

This causes the drawing to look great while zoomed in, but causes the app to run very laggy. The thing that confuses me though, if I change the above code to this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((self.view.frame.size), false, 0.0)
```

And zoom out all the way, the drawing looks exactly the same (granted, I'm zoomed all the way out) but it's no longer laggy. I know this probably isn't coming across super clearly so here's a video showing what happens in the first scenario: https://youtu.be/E_9FKf1pUTY and in the second: https://youtu.be/OofFTS4Q0OA

So basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to treat the zoomed in area as if it was its own view. It seems to me as if the app is updating the entire image view, rather than just the part that is visible at any given time. Is there a way to update only the portion of the image view that is drawn on? Sorry if this is a bit of a confusing post, feel free to ask questions if there's anything you don't understand. Just for clarity sake, I'll include all of the drawing code below:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("Touches began")

    swiped = true

    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.location(in: scrollView)
        lastPoint.x = lastPoint.x / scrollView.zoomScale
        lastPoint.y = lastPoint.y / scrollView.zoomScale
    }
}

func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {
    print("\(fromPoint.x), \(fromPoint.y)")
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((scrollView.frame.size), false, 0.0)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    if erase == true {
        context?.setLineWidth(30)
    }
    if erase == false {
        context?.setLineWidth(CGFloat(sizeVar))
    }
    if color == "black" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "white" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "blue" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "cyan" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.cyan.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "green" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.green.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "magenta" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.magenta.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "red" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    }
    if color == "yellow" {
        context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor.yellow.cgColor)
    }

    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    swiped = true

    if let touch = touches.first {
        var currentPoint = touch.location(in: scrollView)
        currentPoint.x = currentPoint.x / scrollView.zoomScale
        currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y / scrollView.zoomScale
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

        lastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if !swiped {
        drawLines(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: lastPoint)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn about `if else` statements. And consider using a dictionary for your color lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scale parameter in the function `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_:_:_:)` is not a quality setting, and you should not put arbitrary values there. It's a scale factor, and it's akin to the @1x, @2x, and @3x settings for images. It tells the system the scaling factor to use when mapping image pixels to screen pixels. In most (almost all) cases you should use 0, which means "use the native scale of the screen" (@2x for normal retina, or @3x for iPhone 6+ and 7+.) You should never set it to an arbitrary value like 7. That creates an image with 7x as many pixels as normal, and forces the system to scale it for screen drawing every time, which takes more time and is slower.

Next, creating a new image for each new line is a dreadfully inefficient way to do drawing. It creates and releases large blocks of memory constantly, and then has to completely redraw the screen each time. Instead I would set up a view that has a `CAShapeLayer` as it's backing layer and update the path that's installed in the layer.

Comment: Ok well I'm sorry if I'm not fully understanding, but I actually do want to be generating an image with 7x (maybe even 10x) as many pixels as usual. Since I'm zoomed in 10x, I need a sharper image to be able to zoom in so far. I'm just wondering if using the CAShapeLayer would actually help with that. I can only find examples online of using a CAShapeLayer to draw a shape rather than draw a path live. Is there possibly a tutorial online that would show how to use the CAShapeLayer for drawing? I can't find one. Will the CAShapeLayer help with the resolution of my zoomed in drawing? Thanks!

Comment: Your current approach is doomed to be laggy and unresponsive. Yes, shape layers are resolution independent.

Comment: Alright I got it to work and it's really awesome! Everything I'd hoped it to be. The only thing is, in the function where I do all the actual drawing; I try to set the line cap but it won't change. Here's the code:
        let line = CAShapeLayer()
        line.lineCap = kCALineCapRound //but it really doesn't draw smoothly. I'm convinced the line cap line isn't working. Here's what the drawing looks like: https://ibb.co/nAqxGQ Is there any reason the line.lineCap = kCALineCapRound line of code wouldn't be working? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out. Just needed to use line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound rather than line.lineCap = kCALineCapRound. Thanks so much for your help; this works awesome!